# Convert string date

Tags: date

I have a bad date output:

```
Mon Jan 20 17:03:25 CST 2014
```

Is there a tool/function or whatever to convert this string to a more usefull format? Like yyymmdd or something like that.

The output is a string so I have to manipulate it afterwards.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have GNU date?

```
$ date -d"Mon Jan 20 17:03:25 CST 2014" +%Y%m%d
20140121
```

my server is in HKT, that's why it shows 21st Jan

Comment: oh yeah thats it. I can use gdate.